# submitting a form based on input field value

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form that has a few basic fields for now.

```
<input name="model" type="text">
<input name="esn" type="text">
<select name="status">
     <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
     <option value="Ordered">Ordered</option>
     <option value="Received">Received</option>
 </select>
<input type="submit" value="Save Order or Add Payment" />
```

I am allowing my users to edit this form as needed, so basically if the model has been ordered they set the status as ordered then they save it to the db. Those works fine and all but I would like to add a condition that if they select received as the status and they click on the submit button, it would first check that the ESN is not empty. I know I can set "required" on the esn field but if I do that it always asks the users to enter the ESN and I only need them to enter it when they select receive as the status. we are using the form as a way to track our orders and we don't get the esns until we actually received the delivery.

Any advise on how to handle this condition please? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then, you can use addClass removeClass function. Add the class required when the received option is selected.

```
<input name="esn" id="esn" type="text">
<select name="status" id="status">


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#status').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'Received')
            $('#esn').addClass('required');
        else
            $('#esn').removeClass('required');
    });
});
```

Comment: No need to use Jquery for such a simple task. Also pls correct your code to add the class to ESN and not status

Comment: Since he is saying about adding class required, he must be validating the form via jQuery. And I have already corrected. Anyways, thank you

Comment: I decided to go with this one as I am trying to learn jquery but instead of addClas, I used attr instead. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of using attr function, its better to use addClass and removeClass because a class element can have multiple attributes. Attr function also works, but attr function is used to replace the value of attribute. Means, it takes few extra steps if you have multiple classes.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <form method='post' action='somesite.php'>
         <input name="model" type="text">
        <input name="esn" type="text">
        <select name="status">
             <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
             <option value="Ordered">Ordered</option>
             <option value="Received">Received</option>
        <input type="submit" value="Save Order or Add Payment" onclick='return validate();' />
    </form>

    <script> function validate() {
      if(document.getElementsByName('esn')[0].value == "")
{
 alert ('ESN is Empty');
return false;
}
      return true
    } </script>
```

this Will work for u even without jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can call a function on Submit and check the value there something like

```
<input type="button" value="Save Order or Add Payment" onclick="validate(this.form)"/>

function validate(form)
{
if (document.getElementByName(status).value==="Recieved" && document.getElementByName(esn).value==="")
    alert("Please fill ESN");
else
   form.submit();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This you can achieve using JavaScript. Write a condition to check if the user selected received then if the esn is empty return false or show some alert.

```
function checkReceived()
        {
            var s = document.getElementById('status');
            var item1 = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
            if(item1=='Received')
            {
                alert("ens should not empty");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }



<input type="button" value="Save Order or Add Payment" onclick='checkReceived()'/>
```

add id in select box and close the select box properly